# Google Drive API "commenter" permission fails but all others work

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I'm unable to share a folder on the Google Drive API with the [commenter permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) using the [Google API client](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client/versions/0.11.1) gem. I've tried making the same CREATE manually in Postman and I have the same issue. I've confirmed that my access token, user email and `folder_id` are all valid.

```
drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = get_access_token
role = "commenter"
perm = Google::Apis::DriveV3::Permission.new(type: "user", role: role, email_address: email)
drive.create_permission(folder_id, permission_object = perm, email_message: "You've been invited to work on a folder.")
```

Response:
`400 Bad Request. User message: "Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing."`

Comment: Hi there @NathanielTracy-Amoroso! To further help you, could you please try to set the `supportsAllDrives` request parameter to `TRUE` and see if it helps?

Comment: Hi ! As [stated on the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), this method will  exclusively work for **files** and **shared drives**, not for folders in your Drive. Is the folder you are trying to add permissions to in your own Drive?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf The API doesn't really distinguish between files and folders except by mimetype so I would interpret this text to mean you cannot create permissions on folders (especially since it is possible to create permissions on folders with this route). The folder is in drive of the user whose access token is being used.

Comment: Hi ! You are right. I have tested with the roles ```owner```, ```reader``` and ```writer``` and you can actually create permissions on a folder for these. I don't know the reason why ```commenter``` behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to accomplish your goals, but I wasn't able to. After different scenarios and set-ups I ended up with the `Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing.` 400 error. As a result, I reported this behaviour to Google and an [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161335570) was made out of it. You could go and click on `+1` to make this issue more popular.